# Building TMX in the MonoGame Pipeline using MonoGame Extended

Tags: c#, monogame, monogame-extended

I updated MonoGame to the latest development build and noticed the Tiled Map Importer and Processor wasn't in the content pipeline anymore (even after adding both MonoGame Extended Content DLL and MonoGame Extended Tiled Content DLL).

Am I supposed to build TMX maps into .xnb files using the MonoGame XML Importer and No Processing or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're either [using the pre-release NuGet packages](https://github.com/craftworkgames/MonoGame.Extended/wiki/How-to-use-the-pre-release-NuGet-packages) or [building from source](https://github.com/craftworkgames/MonoGame.Extended/wiki/Building-MonoGame.Extended-from-source). Either way, you're using code that changes fairly frequently in the `develop` branch.

It sounds like you're on the right track though. The Tiled content importer has recently been split out from the main one, so referencing it from the MonoGame Content pipeline is the way to go.

The best way to see how things work is to take a look at [the demos](https://github.com/craftworkgames/MonoGame.Extended/tree/develop/Source/Demos/Demo.TiledMaps). We try to keep those up-to-date with the latest changes.

For example, the demo shows that there's now two DLL's referenced in the `Content.mgcb` file.

```
#-------------------------------- References --------------------------------#

/reference:../../../MonoGame.Extended.Content.Pipeline/bin/MonoGame.Extended.Content.Pipeline.dll
/reference:../../../MonoGame.Extended.Content.Pipeline.Tiled/bin/MonoGame.Extended.Content.Pipeline.Tiled.dll
```

The exact path to these files will change depending on if you're building from source or referencing the NuGet package but other than that it's straightforward.

It's not really clear from your question what might be wrong exactly, but I hope this answer leads you in the right direction.

Comment: Weird, because I have both of them referenced like that in my Content.mgcb. I've looked at the demo already, but couldn't find a solution. The importers/processors for MonoGame Extended DDL shows up, but not the ones from MonoGame Extended Tiled DLL